# Android putExtra issue

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have scoured SE and google and found what I thought were decent examples of how to implement `putExtra()` in tandem with `getStringExtra()`.

The trouble I seem to be unable to resolve is that my putExtra data never appears to be getting retrieved from my getStringExtra call in the target activity.

I've tried numerous SE examples where others have asked this question countless times and yet it never seems to get me closer to a working base to expand on.

My primary activity's put is as follows;
(First, I tried this with no luck)

```
    // Click handler for group list items
    lvGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            int gid       = groupIds.get(arg2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(RadSMS_Activity.this, RadSMS_CreateGroup.class);
            intent.putExtra("SELECTED_GROUP_ID", gid);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

(Then, I tried this. Also with no luck.)

```
    // Click handler for group list items
    lvGroups.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            int gid       = groupIds.get(arg2);
            Intent target = new Intent();
            target.putExtra("SELECTED_GROUP_ID", gid);
            Intent intent = new Intent(RadSMS_Activity.this, RadSMS_CreateGroup.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

My target activity that I want to extract the value from is the following;

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.creategroup);

        String strGID = getIntent().getStringExtra("SELECTED_GROUP_ID");
        selectedGID = new Long(strGID);
        // ... additional code would be here
    }
```

*Function truncated for brevity's sake.*

So, according to everything I've seen so far, it appears I'm doing it right, but when I put a breakpoint at the line where selectedGID gets assigned its value, strGID is always null. This is really beginning to make me crazy.

Can anyone please tell me if I have done something incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gid is an int.
You are putting an int.
You appear to be trying to retrieve a string.
Consider:

```
int gid= getIntent().getIntExtra("SELECTED_GROUP_ID",-1);
```

Comment: What version of the SDK does this syntax belong to? Because I am writing mine in 2.2 or SDK 5 and when I try this or Olegas's suggestion, it's not allowing use of those calls.

Comment: Okay...I got the call to work and set the default value to zero, but it's returning zero now, which tells me that the put value of 2 is still not making through to my activity. This seems hopeful, but still not working.

Comment: Forget what I just said. When I return to using my first implementation of the putExtra call...it works like a charm! Thanks a million JAL! :)

Answer (score 1):

You are putting an integer value while getting it as a string. It will always return null. Use intent.getExtras().getInt() instead of intent.getStringExtra().

Comment: What version of the SDK does this syntax belong to? Because I am writing mine in 2.2 or SDK 5 and when I try this or JAL's suggestion, it's not allowing use of those calls.

Comment: All for API level 1. See SDK docs. getInt call must have an argument - a name of extra.